# Access denied exception : testNG java.IOException

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am new to automation testing in selenium
While executing testNG code in java maven project I got following issue :

```
[Utils] [ERROR] Access is denied
*java.io.IOException*: Access is denied
    at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
    at java.io.File.createNewFile(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.Utils.writeFile(*Utils.java:176*)
    at org.testng.internal.Utils.writeFile(*Utils.java:149*)
    at org.testng.reporters.SuiteHTMLReporter.generateTableOfContents(SuiteHTMLReporter.java:611)
    at org.testng.reporters.SuiteHTMLReporter.generateReport(SuiteHTMLReporter.java:69)
    at org.testng.TestNG.generateReports(TestNG.java:1097)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1022)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
[Utils] [ERROR] Access is denied
java.io.IOException: Access is denied
    at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
    at java.io.File.createNewFile(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.Utils.writeFile(Utils.java:176)
    at org.testng.internal.Utils.writeFile(Utils.java:149)
    at org.testng.reporters.SuiteHTMLReporter.generateXmlFile(*SuiteHTMLReporter.java:101*)
    at org.testng.reporters.SuiteHTMLReporter.generateReport(*SuiteHTMLReporter.java:79*)
    at org.testng.TestNG.generateReports(*TestNG.java:1097*)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1022)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
[Utils] [ERROR] Access is denied
java.io.IOException: Access is denied
    at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
    at java.io.File.createNewFile(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.Utils.writeFile(Utils.java:176)
    at org.testng.internal.Utils.writeFile(Utils.java:149)
    at org.testng.reporters.SuiteHTMLReporter.generateIndex(SuiteHTMLReporter.java:170)
    at org.testng.reporters.SuiteHTMLReporter.generateReport(SuiteHTMLReporter.java:82)
    at org.testng.TestNG.generateReports(TestNG.java:1097)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1022)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
```

My classed looks like follows :
TestBase.java

```
public class TestBase {
public static WebDriver driver=null;
public static Properties prop;

public TestBase() {
    try {
        prop = new Properties();
        FileInputStream ip = new FileInputStream(
                System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\src\\main\\java\\com\\qa\\config\\config.properties");
        prop.load(ip);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void initialization() {
    String browserName = prop.getProperty("browser");

    if (browserName.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E:\\Automation_Testing\\AutomationTest\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
    } else if (browserName.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox")) {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    }
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
    driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(TestUtil.PAGE_LOAD_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(TestUtil.IMPLICIT_WAIT,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get(prop.getProperty("url"));
}
}
```

In this class I have written my execution code to create a student in my application. 
Class name : StudentPageTest.java

```
 public class StudentPageTest extends TestBase{

LoginPage loginpage;
 StudentPage studentpage;

 public StudentPageTest() throws Exception {
    super();
}

@BeforeTest
public void setUp() throws IOException {
    initialization();
    loginpage = new LoginPage();
    studentpage = new StudentPage();
}

@Test(priority = 1)
public void loginTest() throws InterruptedException {
    loginpage.login(prop.getProperty("username"), prop.getProperty("password"));
}

@Test(priority = 2)
public void addStudent() throws InterruptedException, IOException {

    studentpage = new StudentPage();
    Thread.sleep(8000);
    studentpage.clickBy(studentpage.studentMenu);
    Thread.sleep(10000);
    studentpage.add_student();
}
}
```

I am calling this method to add student the functionality of this method is that it should create a student in my application

```
public void add_student() throws InterruptedException, IOException {

    clickBy(add_studentBtn);
    Thread.sleep(10000);

    sendText(stud_name, "Nayan");
    Thread.sleep(2000);

    sendText(stud_contactnum, "4565434455");
    Thread.sleep(2000);

    sendText(stud_email, "n1@gmail.com");
    Thread.sleep(2000);

    sendText(parentname, "Prakash");
    Thread.sleep(2000);

    sendText(parent_contactnum, "5543654344");
    Thread.sleep(2000);

    sendText(parent_email, "prksh@gmail.com");
    Thread.sleep(2000);

    clickBy(assigncourselink);



}
```

Please comment if you require anything more to analyse.

Answer (score 0):

While running TestNG ,throwing an error message inconsistely "Test NG
java.io.IOException: Access is denied"

Comment: This does not seem to provide an answer to the question. You can [search for similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)